# AJAX Promises using Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I'm trying to make several AJAX calls (let's say 2) using promises.  Basically I want to be able to merge the two responses together, perform some analysis on them as a whole, then spit out a response.
Right now, I have:

```
var responseArray = [];
for (var i=0; i<letsSayTwo; i++) {
  responseArray.push(someAjaxCall(data));
};
responseArray.done(function(response) {
  var spit = someAnalysis(response);
  console.log(spit);
});
responseArray.fail(function(response) {
  console.log('fail');
});
```

As it stands, I'm getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'done'" error in console.  Am I correct in thinking that I can't use this method?  I looked into using the following bit of code from (http://gregfranko.com/blog/jquery-best-practices/) but I can't seem to get the response that I need.

```
$.when.apply(this, responseArray).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Instead, what I get is [response, "success", response] where the first response is the correct return response for one of the AJAX calls and the last response is the actual call itself.  How should I go about getting the correct responses from both AJAX calls??

I hope this all makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Try following the example in the `$.when()` documentation : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As it stands, I'm getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'done'` error in console. Am I correct in thinking that I can't use this method?

Not on arrays, yes. You can call this method only on Promise and Deferred objects, like the one produced by `$.when.apply(this, responseArray)`

> … but I can't seem to get the response that I need. Instead, what I get is `[response, "success", response]` where the first response is the correct return response for one of the AJAX calls and the last response is the actual call itself.

As stated in the [docs for `$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), it resolves the result promise with **multiple arguments** - and when the input promises themselves did yield multiple values (such as `$.ajax` does), each argument is an arguments object of the respective promise resolution. You were only getting the first of them with `response`, but there are `responseArray.length` (`letsSayTwo`) arguments to the callback.

> How should I go about getting the correct responses from both AJAX calls?

You want to extract the first item (response data) from each [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object, so you can use `map`:

```
$.when.apply(this, responseArray).done(function() {
  var responses = $.map(arguments, function(args) { return args[0]; }),
      spit = someAnalysis(responses);
  console.log(spit);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log('fail: '+textStatus);
});
```

Comment: Got it!  Thanks for explaining it so well.  Just one note, I think the last character on the second line should be a semicolon, not a comma.

Comment: No, it should: That makes it a [multi `var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), declaring `spit` as well.

Comment: Haha of course.  Sorry, I took out the someAnalysis line and it threw an error.  Thanks!