# How can I access the callback arguments of an arbitrary amount of $.get() callbacks when using $.when().then()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am passing an arbitrary amount of deferred get requests to `$.when.apply(this, ajax_calls).done(function() {});` but I do not know how to access the arguments usually passed to the callback of each ajax_call.

I want to access the results of each ajax call in the `.done()` function, maybe in the form:

```
$.when.apply(this, ajax_calls).done(function(resultArray) {
    resultArray.forEach( function(s) {
         console.log(s)
    }
});
```

or something similar.

Is this possible?

Comment: see the documentation of $.when ... https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ ... .done function will get 1 argument per deferred

Comment: See also [this approach for ajax promises](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19090635/1048572)

Comment: I know how to access the deferred results normally, but if I pass an arbitrary amount of deferred calls, then I won't know how many arguments the `done` function will get. Is there a way to access the `done` arguments when I pass an array of args using `$.when.apply()`?

Comment: Both of the questions I linked show you how to use the `arguments` object for a variable amount of results…

Comment: I hadn't seen your answer @Bergi. 

In the answer you linked above: is `arguments` an array of result arrays that `$.when` returns? Is `args` then each of the arrays inside that array? Lastly, should `response` be `responses`, or are the two different variables? If they're different, then what is going on there? Cheers.

Comment: `arguments` is something like an array, yes. Whether it contains arrays or values directly depends whether your original promises resolve with multiple values (like `$.ajax()` ones do) or not.