# jQuery / .when - package up arguments into function?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, promise

[The jQuery doco shows an example where two $.ajax calls are made under the control of a $.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) (page down the 'Examples' heading) .

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) )
  .then( myFunc, myFailure );
```

That's fine but what I would like to do is to define those `$.ajax` calls within a function (where I might do other stuff to prepare for the call).

So something like this :

```
$.when( myAjaxCall1(), myAjaxCall2() )
  .then( goodFetches, badFetches );
```

I have tried that with a functions that look like this :

```
var myAjaxCall1 = function()
{
   return $.ajax('https://httpbin.org/get?Z=Y,X,W');
};
var myAjaxCall2 = function()
{
   return $.ajax('https://httpbin.org/get?A=B,C,D');
};
```

I do get a three element array as an argument to `goodFetches` for each of `myAjaxCall1` and `myAjaxCall2` but it's not the same information as I receive if I just put the `$.ajax` calls straight into the `$.when` as shown in the above example from the documentation.

How should I restructure `myAjaxCall1` and `myAjaxCall2` so that the behaviour is equivalent to :

```
$.when( $.ajax( "https://httpbin.org/get?Z=Y,X,W" ), 
        $.ajax( "https://httpbin.org/get?A=B,C,D" ) )
  .then( goodFetches, badFetches );
```

Comment: I think you can't do that, since the $.ajax call waiting the response from the server so you have no return value while you call the `return` before the server give the response.

Comment: @FadhlyPermata - You can just return the promise from the function which is the same thing that `$.ajax()` returns.

Comment: Your naming of the callbacks `goodFetches, badFetches` suggests you don't exactly understand what `$.when` does. It's more like `.then(allGood, anyBad)` (and just like with any promise, only one of the two will get called).

Comment: The behaviour of `$.when` when being passed ajax promises [is indeed abysimal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19090635/1048572). Switch to a proper promise library if you can.

Comment: Your snippets with and without the ajax calls wrapped in functions are exactly equivalent. `$.when` does not behave differently. I'd suggest you show us what those `goodFetches` and `badFetches` callbacks are and what goes wrong in them (and what you would have expected instead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work just fine in the functions.  You are probably just not accessing the arguments properly from the result.  You get a series of arguments that are each a sub array that contains three elements: `[data, statusText, jqXHR]`.  Those arguments will be the same whether you have your ajax calls in a function or not as long as the function returns the promise.

Here's an example from the jQuery doc:

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
  // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively.
  // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
  var data = a1[ 0 ] + a2[ 0 ]; // a1[ 0 ] = "Whip", a2[ 0 ] = " It"
  if ( /Whip It/.test( data ) ) {
    alert( "We got what we came for!" );
  }
});
```

It makes no difference if the `$.ajax()` calls are directly in the `$.when()` arguments or if you return the promise from a function.  Same result.

---

So, you can do this and you will get the same data back in the `.then()` handler:

```
var myAjaxCall1 = function() {
   return $.ajax('https://httpbin.org/get?Z=Y,X,W');
};

var myAjaxCall2 = function() {
   return $.ajax('https://httpbin.org/get?A=B,C,D');
};

$.when( myAjaxCall1(), myAjaxCall2() ).then(function(a1, a2) {
      // a1[0] is data from first ajax call
      // a2[0] is data from second ajax call
});
```