# Working with 1 or more jQuery promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I'm making either 1 or more REST/ajax calls to validate some user information. The rest calls are working well and the information is coming back. The issue I'm facing isn't with that part of the code, which looks something like this.

```
function ensureUsers(recipients){
  var promises = [];
  for(var key in recipients){
      var payload = {'property':recipients[key]};
      promises.push( $.ajax({...}));
  }
  return $.when.apply($,promises);    
}

....

ensureUsers(users) // users is an array of 1 or more users
  .done(function(){
     console.log(arguments);
  )}
```

If there is more than one user in the initial array, then the arguments in my `.done` code are structured like this:

```
[[Object,"success",Object],[Object,"success",Object]...]
```

I can then iterate over each result, check the status, and proceed.

However if there is only one user in the initial array then `.done` gets arguments like this:

```
[Object,"success",Object]
```

It seems strange to me that the structure of what is returned would change like that. I couldn't find anything about this specific a problem, so I hacked together a solution

```
var promises = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
if(!Array.isArray(promises[0])){
    promises = [promises];  
}
```

Is that really the best I can hope for? Or is there some better way to deal with the returned promises from 1 or more ajax calls in jQuery?

Comment: you must be doing something wrong, because I don't see any difference (except with the number of arguments) regardless

Comment: Jaromanda -- So for you arguments.length is equal to the number of calls you make? I don't see what I could possible be doing wrong? There are no conditionals or anything that would make it return something different.

Comment: yep, arguments.length is always the number of calls made - however, the code I checked with didn't use $.ajax, just $.Deferred, but I wouldn't think that would make a difference - which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: We are using 1.8.3. Maybe it is time to update a bit?

Comment: I don't really know ... I just asked so I can tell you what version I tested with (1.12.4)

Comment: End of my day. I'll give it at try tomorrow. Thanks for the ideas. So far my hacky solution seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems strange to me that the structure of what is returned would change like that.

Yes, jQuery is horribly inconsistent here. When you pass a single argument to `$.when`, it tries to cast it to a promise, when you pass multiple ones it suddenly tries to wait for all of them and combine their results. Now throw in that jQuery promises can resolve with multiple values (arguments), and [add a special case for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19090635/1048572).

So there are two solutions I could recommend:

- Drop `$.when` completely and just use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) instead of it:

  ```
  var promises = [];
  for (var p of recipients) {
      …
      promises.push( $.ajax({…}));
  }

  Promise.all(promises)
  .then(function(results) {
       console.log(results);
  })
  ```
- Make each promise resolve with only a single value (unlike `$.ajax()` that resolves with 3) so that they don't get wrapped in an array, and `$.when` will produce consistent results regardless of number of arguments:

  ```
  var promises = [];
  for (var p of recipients) {
      …
      promises.push( $.ajax({…}).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          return data;
      }) );
  }

  $.when.apply($, promises)
  .then(function() {
       console.log(arguments);
  })
  ```

Answer (score 1):

It appears this functionality is working as currently [documented](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/). When you have multiple deferreds passed to `$.when` it creates a new `Promise` object that is resolved with the results of each of the results of the passed in deferreds. When you only pass in one, it returns the deferred that you passed in, thus only returning the result instead of an array of results.

I'm not sure if it is any better than your current solution, but you could force it to always have multiple deferreds by having a "fake" deferred that you skip when evaluating the results.

I.E.

```
function ensureUsers(recipients){
  var promises = [$.Deferred().resolve()];
  for(var key in recipients){
    var payload = {'property':recipients[key]};
    promises.push( $.ajax({...}));
  }
  return $.when.apply($,promises);    
}
```

You could also potentially make it so the placeholder deferred is resolved with the same structure as what you expect in your real results so it would just appear that the first response is always a success.