# jQuery deferreds - order of execution in multiple blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, es6-promise, jquery-deferred

**NOTE**
*This problem somehow happens only with a specific server-side api. Therefore it addresses the wrong problem. I'll not delete it since it have answers and comments.*

---

I'm trying to execute a few ajax requests, do some stuff after each is done and some other stuff after all of them are done, for that I'm using the code below:

```
let
        myarr = [],
        myfunc = arg => myarr.push(arg);

$.when(
    $.post(myparams).done(myfunc),
    $.post(otherparams).done(myfunc),
    $.post(yetanother).done(myfunc)

// it comes out with only one arg
).then(e => console.log(myarr));
```

But when it comes to execute the `then` block it usually has only executed the `done` of the first operation, how could I fix that?

I'm sorry if it's a duplicate but honestly I didn't even knew what to search for :/

---

**Comment**

I also tried to create my own deferreds where I would execute the ajax and resolve them inside the `done` block, but that yielded the same results.

Using only `done` or only `then`, same.

Comment: Never use `done`, always use `then`.

Comment: @Bergi *"Never use `done`"* - why so absolute? The use-case for `then` and `done` are not one in the same. What if you only want the callback to occur if the deferred is resolved?

Comment: same thing happens using only `done` or only `then`

Comment: @TylerRoper I'm simplifying of course. Still I haven't found a use case for `done` where `then` doesn't work as well, and given there are too many pitfalls with `done` I recommend to generally avoid it.

Comment: @LucasNoetzold Is that your exact code? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Bergi I'll adapt something... few moments

Comment: I'm not managing to recreate this condition with any other url besides the api I have. Must be something with it, if that is possible somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per jQuery's documentation on [`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/):

> Each argument *[of `.then()`]* is an array with the following structure: `[ data, statusText, jqXHR ]`

Meaning you could do something like this...

```
$.when(
  $.post(myparams),
  $.post(otherparams),
  $.post(yetanother)
).then((res1, res2, res3) => { //Arg for each result
  myfunc(res1[0]);             //Call myfunc for result 1's data
  myfunc(res2[0]);             //Call myfunc for result 2's data
  myfunc(res3[0]);             //Call myfunc for result 3's data
});
```

Though perhaps a cleaner version might be something like this instead...

```js
let
  myarr = [],
  myfunc = arg => myarr.push(arg);

$.when(
  $.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'),
  $.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2'),
  $.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3')
).then((...results) => {                  //Get all results as an array
  results.map(r=>r[0]).forEach(myfunc);   //Call myfunc for each result's data
  console.log(myarr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, [jQuery's `when` function is weird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40144598/1048572) especially [toghether with `$.ajax`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19090635/1048572). Better [just use ES6 `Promise.all`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31327725/1048572)