# jQuerys jqXHR deferreds fail to chain with $.when(...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I want to wait for multiple promises to be resolved. The method of choice is using jQuery's `$.when()` function to wait for all of them:

```
let test = $.Deferred();
$.getJSON('test.json')
    .done((content) => {
        test.resolve(content);
    });

$.when(
    test,
    $.when(17)
).done((testContent, value) => {
    console.log('test content: ' + testContent.first);
    console.log('value: ' + value);
});
```

The used test JSON file (`test.json`) looks like this:

```
{
  "first": "one",
  "second": "two"
}
```

The expected and actual output on the console is:

```
test content: one
value: 17
```

**But:** (Lo And Behold!)

```
$.when(
    $.getJSON('test.json'),
    $.when(17)
).done((testContent, value) => {
    console.log('test content: ' + testContent.first);
    console.log('value: ' + value);
});
```

With this code, the output changes to:

```
test content: undefined
value: 17
```

WHAT? undefined? Please note that the only difference in code is that the `$.getJSON` function is used directly as one of the deferreds in the `$.when` instruction instead of being extracted to a separate deferred.

Why? What's the difference?

It seems to me like jqXHR style deferreds are not 100 % compatible to jQuery's `$.when` function.

- jqXHR deferred are used correctly for the extra promise "test"
- the extra deferred "test" can be used in `$.when`

Why does this work, but I cannot use the `$.getJSON` jqXHR object directly in the `$.when` function?

I am using jQuery 3.2.1.

**Update 29.04.2017**

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andimeier/cwd6z9at/).

As you can see, if I embedd the jqXHR promise directly in the `$.when` instruction, the result of this promise is not only the JSON value, but an array of:

```
[ JSONValue, statusCode, XHR ]
```

Why does jqXHR behave differently in `$.when` then when used outside of `$.when`?

Comment: What does `console.log(testContent)` show?

Comment: @Barmar: see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/andimeier/cwd6z9at  testContent is `JSONPayload` in the first variant - and an array `[ JSONPayload, statusCode, XHR ]` in the second variant, see my update of the original post

Comment: Does it help to say "because [jQuery deferreds are weird](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088981/ajax-promises-using-array)", and that you never should try to resolve a promise with multiple arguments?

Comment: @Bergi: yes indeed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an array of values because `jqXHR` resolves to multiple values (the 3 arguments that are normally passed to the `.done()` method). From the [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) documentation:

> If a Deferred resolved to a single value, the corresponding argument will hold that value. In the case where a Deferred resolved to multiple values, the corresponding argument will be an array of those values.

So you need to index or destructure the result to get the value you want.

```
$.when(
    $.getJSON('test.json'),
    $.when(17)
).done(([testContent, textStatus, jqXHR], value) => {
    console.log('test content: ' + testContent.first);
    console.log('value: ' + value);
});
```

You're not seeing this when you use the separate promise, because you're just resolving it with a single value in

```
(content) => {
    test.resolve(content);
}
```

You would see the same array behavior if you passed all the parameters when resolving the promise:

```js
let test = $.Deferred();
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/bmguh')
  .done((content, status, jqXHR) => {
    test.resolve(content, status, jqXHR);
  });

$.when(
  test,
  $.when(17)
).done((testContent, value) => {
  console.log('Separate promise:', JSON.stringify(testContent));
});

// jqXHR used directly in $.when:
$.when(
  $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/bmguh'),
  $.when(17)
).done((testContent, value) => {
  console.log('jqXHR used directly:', JSON.stringify(testContent));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah I noticed what the array of 3 values was meant to be. BUT: why does the deferred resolve to an array of 3 values when the deferred is used in `$.when` construct - but the same deferred resolves to a single value (the JSON data) when used outside of a `$.when` construct? This is the main point of confusion for me and the reason why I posted this problem in the first place. Why are there different results?

Comment: I updated the fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/andimeier/cwd6z9at/) so that the resolved value in the "separate" promise is also shown: as you can see, this is only a single value. Only in the context of `$.when` it resolves to an array of 3 values. => ?

Comment: Your indirect code is just resolving the promise with one value when it does `.resolve(content)`. When you use the jqXHR directly, it's doing the equivalent of`.resolve(content, status, jqXHR)`.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I overlooked the fact that even a separate promise would resolve into THREE values. I assumed that resolving into multiple values woulf always result in an array for a "done" function. But indeed only $.when has this special behavior. You pointed me in the right direction. Thanks a lot, Barmar!